# Print menu item in two lines.... CSS

Tags: .net, css

I built a db driven menu..... However, Since there are several items, the menu appears in two lines. So, I was thinking of breaking the menuitem into two lines.. can u let me know how i can do this?

this is my css file

```
    .menu
   {
width: 900px;
    }
    .menu ul
   {
list-style: none;
max-width: 900px;

   }
  .menu li
 {
list-style: none;
display:inline;
float: left;
height: 53px;
line-height: 53px;
  }

.menu li a
 {
display: inline;
float: left;
color: #852917;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 53px;
max-width:120px; 
text-decoration: none;

background: #ebdbca url(menu_037_bg.jpg) no-repeat left;
border-bottom: 2px solid #d7a278;
}
 .menu li a:hover
 {
width: 120px;
white-space: pre-wrap;
color: #fff;
background: #a73e29 url(menu_037_h.jpg) no-repeat left;
border-bottom: 2px solid #b75542;
   }
  .menu li ul{

    border-left:2px solid #a80329;
    border-right:2px solid #a80329;
    border-bottom:2px solid #a80329;
    display:none;
    height:auto;
    width:120px;
    filter:alpha(opacity=95);
    opacity:0.95;
    position:absolute;

    z-index:200;
    /*top:1em;
    /*left:0;*/
    }
.menu li:hover ul{
    display:block;
    }
```

Comment: could you provide us with at least html and possibly a website or fiddle with your page

Comment: "the menu appears in two lines … I was thinking of breaking the menuitem into two lines" - if it displays as two lines, what to split anymore?

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) reproduction of your menu? I'll fix it for you but aside that Diodeus answer is all you should need.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tJGx5/.. thisis the jsfiddle link

Comment: Don't post your .NET code, post the OUTPUT (HTML). jsFiddle doesn't execute .NET

Comment: K. i've placed html...... u can just check it..

Comment: i changed the css a lot but I dont know why fiddle is displaying my result so badly..... but my output looks lot better than the way it showed up

Comment: Haha this is why I hate .NET lets see if I can get it right without touching the html

Comment: It comes into the second line in te fiddle..... but my app is just hiding the text when i fix width..

Comment: do you have an absolute url for me for `menu_037_bg.jpg` and `menu_037_h.jpg` ?

Comment: go into google and type in image names......the first ones are the ones that we need

Comment: Uh, do you need it to be horizontal? If so it's not smart to make it multiline sine it has submenus which can overlap the links of the second row...

Comment: yeah..right now it is horizontal..after client meeting it can be changed

Comment: @sg3s let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2634/discussion-between-user838359-and-sg3s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the menu finally... two line dropdown....

http://jsfiddle.net/tJGx5/34/

Take it as an example, two line dropdowns don't work well :p

Update: fixed z-index bug in IE

Answer (score 2):

Some best practices for styling list-based menus:

1) Don't style the `LI` (other than resetting margins, padding and using `float:left` if needed).

2) Use `display:block` and put **all** styling on the `A` tag. You don't need `display: inline;`
`float: left`; or any other positioning code. Just set your width, padding margin, fonts and colours and you're all set. Long text will automatically wrap to two lines.

Comment: Yup, I've got the grey hair on that one. :)